# Return years of first and last non-NA values for each column R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   group [3]
      group   year    value1  value2  value3
      <int>   <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1     1       2000    NA      3       4
2     1       2001    8       3       4
3     1       2002    4       3       NA
4     2       2000    NA      NA      1
5     2       2001    9       NA      1
6     2       2002    1       NA      NA
7     3       2000    NA      5       NA
8     3       2001    9       5       NA
9     3       2002    NA      5       NA
```

I need a script that returns the years of the first and last non-na value for each column, irrespective of group. Ideally, the output would look like this. Beware the actual dataset is much larger.

```
          start   end
value 1   2001    2002
value 2   2000    2002
value 3   2000    2001
```

Comment: Souldn't it be `2001` for `value 1` in column `end`? Your wrote __irrespective of group__, which means you don't care about the group column, right?

Comment: @MacOS it seems to be the `max` value of year

Comment: @akrun Thank you! I went through it row by row. Damn it.

Comment: We should consider editing the question.

Comment: @MacOS I was also literally following the OP's title earlier, then I found some inconsistency in the results and changed it

Comment: @akrun I did read the text, and it did not help me either. The text does not highlight `min` and `max` intention behind the question. Instead, I got the impression of doing it row by row. Kudos to you! you where faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reshape into 'long' format and then do a group by  the 'name' and `summarise` to get the `min` and `max`  'year'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>%
   select(-group) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols  = starts_with('value'), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise(start = min(year), end = max(year))  %>%
   column_to_rownames('name')
#        start  end
#value1  2001 2002
#value2  2000 2002
#value3  2000 2001
```

---

Or with `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), id.var = c('year', 'group'), na.rm = TRUE)[,
     .(start = min(year), end = max(year)), .(variable)]
```

---

Or we could also make use of `summarise_at`

```
df1 %>%
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('value')), ~ 
       list(range(year[!is.na(.)]))) %>% 
    unnest(everything()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(everything())
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2000L, 
    2001L, 2002L), value1 = c(NA, 8L, 4L, NA, 9L, 1L, NA, 9L, 
    NA), value2 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L), value3 = c(4L, 
    4L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: Changing to min/max instead of first/last worked for me. I should have specified the year column wasn't in a date format. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

A base solution wehre we find first not `NA` in `year` for the mentioned columns `value1` to `value3`.

```
data.frame(t(sapply(paste0("value", 1:3), function(i){
val_i <- df1[ , i]

data.frame(start = 
df1$year[min(which(!is.na(val_i)))], end= 
df1$year[max(which(!is.na(val_i)))])
})))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option. Not sure if using `names(.SD)` is recommended but it should scale pretty well

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, .(val = names(.SD),
               start = lapply(.SD, function(x) min(year[!is.na(x)])),
               end = lapply(.SD, function(x) max(year[!is.na(x)]))), .SDcols = startsWith(names(df1), "value")]

      val start  end
1: value1  2001 2002
2: value2  2000 2002
3: value3  2000 2001
```